# "Pachorra" e "pachorrento/a": paciente ou lerdo?

Tags: significado, uso-de-palavras, castelhano

A palavra *[pachorra](https://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/Pachorra)* significa tanto "lerdice" como "paciência", mas qual dos dois significados é o mais comum? É uma questão de contexto? Tem mudado no tempo o significado mais habitual?

Vi pela primeira vez *pachorrento* em português enquanto lia *Os Maias*, onde o significado é generalmente "paciente" ou "devagar":

> …as procissões passando num rumor de pachorrenta penitência por tardes de sol e de poeira…
>
> A viúva, D. Eugénia, limitava-se a ser uma excelente e pachorrenta senhora, de agradável nutrição…

Tem outros casos onde a palavra sugere simplesmente lentidão no sentido físico:

> Os guardas rolavam pachorrentamente as bagagens.
>
> Do fim da mesa uma voz dizia, pachorrenta e cantada…

Minha dúvida vem do fato da palavra ter sido adotada pelo português desde o espanhol. Nesse idioma tem os mesmos significados, mas o significado mais pejorativo ("lerdice", "sem vontade") parece ter sido o mais habitual desde há muito tempo, e é o único usado hoje. É uma palavra do registro coloquial e seria terrivelmente desrespeitoso falar de uma senhora ou uma procissão como *pachorrienta*. É assim também em português?

Comment: Não conhecia esses significados. Sempre ouvi "pachorra" como sinônimo de atrevimento ou audácia: "Como você tem a pachorra de falar isso?" quer dizer "Como você se atreve a falar isso?" ou "Como você tem a audácia de falar isso?" - mas faz muito tempo que não escuto essa palavra

Comment: Sério? Isso é em pt-BR ou pt-PT? Eu achei [este blog](http://delamallorcaextrema.blogspot.com.ar/2008/10/trmino-pachorra-por-gente-que-sabe.html) onde alguém fala do mesmo assunto mas em espanhol.

Comment: Em pt-BR, mas não sei a abrangência (talvez fosse apenas uma gíria regional). E já faz muito tempo mesmo que não escuto, talvez nem seja mais tão usada...

Comment: @Hugo Infelizmente tenho visto essa palavra ser usada dessa forma. Não sei de onde sai esse barbarismo, mas é uma evidente inovação. O significado tradicional da palavra é paciência, não ousadia.

Comment: Não sei o quão confiável é esse site, mas tem ambos os significados (audácia/ousadia e paciência): http://www.dicionarioinformal.com.br/pachorra/ - acho que "ousadia" não é um uso muito difundido, mas achei alguns links: http://televisao.uol.com.br/noticias/redacao/2014/09/10/sexo-e-as-negas-recebe-denuncias-de-racismo-e-tv-globo-e-autuada.htm, http://bit.ly/2nvgbWH, http://m.zerohora.com.br/284/noticias/4845452/brasileiros-que-ousaram-falar-mal-dos-gauchos-tem-oportunidade-de-se-retratar e https://danisetudo.wordpress.com/2015/03/20/tpm-tenha-pena-de-mim/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No minha experiência em Portugal, ***pachorra*** é usado na aceção 1 da [Infopédia:](https://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/lingua-portuguesa/pachorra)

> 1. capacidade de suportar contrariedades, incómodos e dificuldades com calma e tranquilidade; paciência ⟨*o João tem uma pachorra!*⟩
> 2. falta de diligência ou de pressa; vagar; lentidão

Não me recordo de ouvir *pachorra* usado na segunda aceção. É usado sobretudo para indicar indiretamente que algo ou alguém é muito maçador ou irritante:

> É preciso uma pachorra para te aturar.
>
> Não tenho pachorra para as teimosias dele.
>
> Primeiro queria ir à praia. Depois não queria. Agora já quer outra vez. Não há pachorra!

*Pachorra* não é pejorativo nesta aceção. A pessoa para quem é precisa ou para quem não se tem pachorra é que é criticada.

Agora, no uso a que eu estou habituado, ***pachorrento*** significa ‘vagaroso’, tal como na aceção 1 da [Infopédia:](https://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/lingua-portuguesa/pachorrento)

> 1. que age ou se move com  calma, lentidão; vagaroso; lento
> 2. que tem pachorra; paciente

Novamente, não me recordo de encontrar *pachorrento* na aceção 2. Curiosamente é esta aceção, ‘paciente’, que corresponde à aceção usual de *pachorra*. Nunca me tinha dado conta deste desencontro dos significados usuais. *Pachorrento* não é particularmente elogioso, mas também não é pejorativo. Os usos d’*Os Maias* seriam ainda hoje perfeitamente normais. Mas *pachorrento* não é tão comum como *pachorra*.

Como referido nos comentários acima, *pachorra* aparece com o significado de ‘ousadia, desfaçatez’ no [DicionárioInformal](http://www.dicionarioinformal.com.br/pachorra/). Eu desconhecia esse uso. Também não aparece nos dicionários convencionais. Poderá ter surgido via ‘calma’: *teve a pachorra (‘calma, descontração’) de me fazer aquela proposta indecente*.

Comment: Conheço "pachorra" com o significado 1 também, e nunca ouvi com o significado de "atrevimento".  Por outro lado, não é uma palavra comum na cidade onde vivo.  Acho que meus filhos nem sabem o que significa.  Acho também que conheço a palavra pelo contato com meus parentes portugueses.  Meus avós e minha mãe usavam com frequência: "hoje não estou com a pachorra pra isso".  Já "pachorrento" eu nunca ouvi.

Comment: @Centaurus, sim, *pachorra* é muito mais comum que *pachorrento/a*.